# How can I run reaction-next-starterkit of reactioncommerce in Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I've been trying to install and run Reaction Commerce with [Reaction Plataform](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/installation-reaction-platform) using Windows.

I followed all the steps, however after the `make` command the `reaction-next-starterkit` doesn't run (I checked using `docker ps`), and even trying `make start` it also doesn't work.

I checked the logs with `docker-compose logs -f`, and the output doesn't show me many things:

> ': No such file or directory'sh
>
> reaction-next-starterkit_web_1 exited with code 127

And I tried running with [other method](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-next-starterkit), like this:

`docker-compose up -d` - inside the reaction-next-starterkit folder, but also don't keep that running.

I checked all of the containers (including the not running) and I see all of them.

Comment: You are probably running it as a Windows container and you need to switch to Linux containers based on error message you got.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I'm running on Linux containers, I've found the anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [this issue](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-docs/issues/706) there is a config of Git in Windows that change some files when you make a `git clone` of any repo, in that specific case it make some projects to break.

So, the solution was to change the specific configuration:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Then `make clean` to delete everything made until now, delete the cloned repository, and [start from scratch](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/installation-reaction-platform).